# How to get datatype and such, for only one column of a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I usually have to check datatype a particular tablecolumn via a sql code, for which I use

```
desc tablename
```

Some tables I look at have a lot of columns, and I think it would be nice if there's a way to get the description for only a particular column (or columns).

Does anyone know of a way to get that info for only a particular (set of) column(s)?

For example something like the beneath would be nice, and possibly there already is?

```
desc tablename.column_name
```

Comment: Based on the answers, I made a query like beneath.

Select table_name, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, data_length, case when data_type='VARCHAR2' then data_length/4 else 
DATA_PRECISION end data_precision,  CHAR_USED From ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
Where TABLE_NAME = UPPER('tablename') 
and COLUMN_NAME in (UPPER ('columnA'), UPPER('columnB'));

Still struggling with the conversion I made for data_length for VARCHAR whether that is correct. I'm deep diving into that some other time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on the answer provided by Radim , You not only need the datatype but also the precision for when it comes to datatypes like varchar2(20).

```
Select TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_PRECISION From ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
Where TABLE_NAME = UPPER('TABLE_NAME') and COLUMN_NAME = UPPER('COLUMN_NAME')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` system catalog views

```
Select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE From ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
Where TABLE_NAME = UPPER('TAB NAME') and COLUMN_NAME = UPPER('COL NAME')
```